# Update protoc-gen-grpc-web on Linux

Tags: angular, grpc-web

I installed grpc-web and the protoc-gen-grpc-web through npm. So when I do `npm list -g | grep grpc` I get

```
➜  frontend git:(master) ✗ npm list -g | grep grpc     
├─┬ @grpc-gen/protoc-gen-grpc-web@0.4.0
├── grpc-web@1.0.3
├─┬ protoc-gen-grpc@1.2.3
```

Then I tried to update the protoc-gen-grpc-web plugin to the latest release `1.0.3` but I'm not sure how I should do that.

I downloaded `protoc-gen-grpc-web-1.0.3-linux-x86_64` from the release page on https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/releases and replaced the file `protoc-gen-grpc-web` in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@grpc-gen/protoc-gen-grpc-web/bin/`. But still `npm list` lists version `0.4.0`. So how exactly should that work?

Comment: for macOS run `brew install protoc-gen-grpc-web`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'@grpc-gen/protoc-gen-grpc-web' and 'protoc-gen-grpc' are not npm packages maintained by us (i.e. the "grpc" organization on Github). You are correct to download the `protoc-gen-grpc-web` plugin from our release page: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/releases

Comment: And what do I do with it then? Sorry for the stupid question but to replace the existing protoc-gen-grpc-web didn't work out.

Comment: I ended up going back to grpc-web@1.0.0 and protoc-gen-grpc-web@0.4.0 as there were some strange compile issues with the latest release. Maybe it was my fault but currently I don't have the time to investigate.